# Create graph with RRD tools on Linux Terminal

Tags: database, linux, paint

my teacher of IT gave me a task, to create script, that prints mine own chosen data on Linux terminal by using RRD tool. Main problems is that I don't even know, how this tool works. I tried to google for tutorials, but I didn't find anything, that could be clear for me.

So, can anybody bring me some examples or explanations, how this tools works, how to create Database for it and add data to it.

Thanks

Comment: What is RRD? (And why is this question tagged as "paint"?)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool
For short, it's database tool, with which you can do many things, but one of the function is to draw (paint) your data in terminal screen, for example.